# Handlng duplicate interface

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am new to objective-c and I want to have two interface

I am trying to reduce peer-dependency in my code so I moved `.m` files and am creating single `.h` files

I did this

```
@interface XyzHelper : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

+ (bool)isFlaggedAsRequested:(NSString * _Nonnull)handlerId;

+ (void)flagAsRequested:(NSString * _Nonnull)handlerId;

@end

@interface XyzHelper : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

but it says `Duplicate interface definition` which makes sense

Any idea how I can fix it?

#### What I am doing?

I am creating a libraries which use

1. https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-incall-manager

and

1. https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions

I don't want user to `npm instal`l both repo (and other repo's I might have) instead a single repo `npm install xyz`

react-native-permissions uses

`@interface XyzHelper : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>`

and

in-call manager have this

```
@interface XyzHelper : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

+ (bool)isFlaggedAsRequested:(NSString * _Nonnull)handlerId;

+ (void)flagAsRequested:(NSString * _Nonnull)handlerId;

@end

@interface XyzHelper : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

### what did I tried?

I tried creating a common interface

```
@interface XyzHelper : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
+ (bool)isFlaggedAsRequested:(NSString * _Nonnull)handlerId;
+ (void)flagAsRequested:(NSString * _Nonnull)handlerId;
@end
```

but this gives duplicate symbol for a architecture x86_64

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? How do you want to use `XyzHelper`?

Comment: So you want to have the same class name, but with different implementations?

Answer (score 2):

`@interface XyzHelper` is declared twice. Of course this is a Duplicate interface definition. Instead you could **extend** your XyzHelper class. In Objective-C often refered to as so called **category**. 
Given a class like the following..

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface XyzHelper : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>
+ (bool)isFlaggedAsRequested:(NSString *)handlerId;
+ (void)flagAsRequested:(NSString *)handlerId;
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

The extension could look like the following example. It does not only extend XyzHelper, it also declares it conforms to an extra protocol.

```
@interface XyzHelper (SomeAudioPlayerExtension) <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@end
```

But keep in mind when doing so you have to check if your class object conforms to a particular protocol when you want to call extra protocol methods from within the former class implementation. Why? Because the extension suggests you conform to protocol while the needed methods are maybe not available, in example the extension implementation could not be loaded or you just forgot to implement them (missing symbols). Or it was just not linked. It is anyway safer to check for conformity at least once before calling any protocol method.

Typically the file names should express they contain extended code by naming them after the classname plus extensionname. So: `XyzHelper+SomeAudioPlayerExtension.h` and `XyzHelper+SomeAudioPlayerExtension.m`